# monitor linux processes for a long period of time and save it into a text file or csv file

Tags: linux, performance, io, cpu, monitor

I am running a stability test which involve several important processes I want to be able to monitor those processes individually (CPU,memory, IO, etc) , i know I can use TOP command but using this command will result in seeing only live metrics and now overall or average which I can derive into a graph and see how it was over time. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `top`, printing the output of a single instance to a file, then using `grep` to isolate the processes you want to see, and then using `awk` to select the fields you want.

Something like

```
top -n 1 -b > /tmp/log_top_running ; grep <process_name> /tmp/log_top_running | awk '{print $10}' >> <report_file>
```

will extract the process running time and append it to the report file. `-b` is to avoid escape chars in the file, `-n 1` terminates `top` after the first refresh.

This is the most basic thing you can do - you can probably do something smarter by passing to `top` the flags to only print the stuff you want to see.

To have it execute regularly you can write this command in a script and use the `watch` command, setting an interval in seconds with the `-n` option. After you have your file you can plot it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it works but i can't see the name of the columns (e.g. %CPU, %MEM , etc) how can i maintain that?

Comment: Before starting the data collection do a `grep` with the string `MEM` and the report file should have the right headers.

Comment: Edited to save to a temporary file, to avoid having to cleanup. Just check there is no file with that name, or change it accordingly.

Comment: If I want to get several metrics for processes can I do it in the same command as above or should I make every line with different process name?

Comment: Yes, you can print several columns at once with something like `awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'`, for instance.

Comment: thanks that helps but i meant if i want to monitor several processes should i write a new line with a new grep like:
top -n 1 -b > /tmp/log_top_running ; grep <process_name_0> /tmp/log_top_running | awk '{print $10}' >> <report_file>

top -n 1 -b > /tmp/log_top_running ; grep <process_name_1> /tmp/log_top_running | awk '{print $10}' >> <report_file>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145396/discussion-between-adriano-angelone-and-erezn).